# So im trying to make a embed be read as something else

Tags: html, embed

I'm currently trying to embed a game into my HTML file so its unblocked but I cant figure out a way so that the embed is read as another embed i.e. a educational site or something. but still plays the game

I just tried

due to it being the embed the website provided, yet it still said it was blocked.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.